# MYSQL return average from another table even if there are no values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with info about art called ART and another called ratings

```
artid  title    artist               artid   userid   rating
----------------------               -----------------------
1      sunset   paul                 1       7        1
2      cows     jane                 1       10       5
```

I need a select statement that will give me all the rows and in ART and the average rating if there are any, for example

```
for example
artid   title   artist   averagerating
--------------------------------------
1       sunset  paul     3
2       cows    jane     NULL
```

the closest i've gotten is
    SELECT *, AVG(rating) FROM art LEFT JOIN reviews ON art.artid = reviews.artid;

but it only returns

```
artid   title   artist   averagerating
--------------------------------------
1       sunset  paul     3
```

It wont return anything that doesn't have a rating for it in the ratings table.
Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `group by`:

```
SELECT art.*, AVG(reviews.rating)
FROM art LEFT JOIN
     reviews
     ON art.artid = reviews.artid
GROUP BY art.artid;
```

When you have an aggregation function (such as `AVG()`) in the `SELECT` clause, the query is an aggregation query.  With no `GROUP BY`, the query always returns exactly one row.